# ORA-00984: column not allowed here while inserting using sql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table(my_routine) with the below structure

```
  Name                Null     Type
```

---

```
MY_ID              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
TEMPLATE_NAME            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255) 
TEMPLATE_ID              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
ASSIGN_FL       NOT NULL CHAR(1)       
SYSTEM_FL          CHAR(1)       
DELETE_FL       NOT NULL CHAR(1)       
VERSION_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
P_ID              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

I tried to insert data into this table based on the output from another table. So I wrote a procedure to perform the task, However I have problem while inserting the values into the table.

I am getting the below error

```
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
ORA-06512: at line 21
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
```

Below is the procedure I have written to perform the insertion task

```
DECLARE RCOUNT NUMBER(10);
I NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(TEMPLATE_ID) INTO RCOUNT FROM MY_TEMPLATE WHERE %SOME_CONDITION%;
I := 1;
WHILE I <= RCOUNT LOOP
DECLARE TEMPLATEID NUMBER(10);
MYNAME VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
   --CTEID := 10;
   --CTENAME := 'QWER';
           SELECT TEMPLATE_ID INTO TEMPLATEID FROM MY_TEMPLATE WHERE ID = I;
  SELECT MY_NAME INTO MYNAME FROM MY_TEMPLATE WHERE ID = I;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I || TEMPLATEID || MYNAME);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_ROUTINE VALUES(I,MYNAME,TEMPLATEID,N,N,N,1,1)';
  I := I + 1;
END;   
END LOOP;
END;
```

Let me know if there is anything wrong in the procedure
Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Why are you using a anonymous block inside the loop. Here you can do it directly.

Comment: You've not quoted `N` characters in the `execute immediate` statement correctly hence the `N` is considered as a column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use execute immediate here, use a regular statement and use the variables directly:

```
insert into my_routing 
values (I,MYNAME,TEMPLATEID, 'N','N','N',1,1);
```

Btw: it's good coding style to always state the columns in the insert statement:

```
insert into my_routine 
  (my_id, template_id, name, assign_fl, system_fl, delete_fl, version-id, p_id)
values 
  (I,MYNAME,TEMPLATEID, 'N','N','N',1,1);
```

But you don't need the slow and inefficient PL/SQL loop at all. What you want to do, can be done without PL/SQL in a single statement:

```
insert into my_routine (my_id, template_id, name, assign_fl, system_fl, delete_fl, version-id, p_id)
select id, template_id, my_name, 'N','N','N',1,1
from my_template
where %some_condition%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the same by using bind variables(If execute immediate needed) like below

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO MY_ROUTINE VALUES(I,:MYNAME,:TEMPLATEID,N,N,N,1,1)' using MYNAME,TEMPLATEID
```

Please refer binding at runtime http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_execute_immediate.htm